# What is a deprecated annotation target - implementation, interface or both?

Tags: java, interface, annotations

I wonder, if I have to annotate a `@Deprecated` method at all their occurrences e.g: Interface, Base (Abstract Class) and all the Implementation Classes or is one annotation in the Interface sufficient?

Comment: This question leans towards being opinion based. However, I would say that deprecating the interface method would suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually depends of how deprecated classes are used. Deprecate an interface (methods or attributes) is enough if you use *good practices* (instantiating the interface to use the implementation).

Anyway,

- you cannot ensure / force this practice in other users
- not all compilers/parsers will throw a warning or show javadoc `@deprecated` tag

  > Using the `@Deprecated` annotation to deprecate a class, method, or field ensures that all compilers will issue warnings when code uses that program element. In contrast, there is no guarantee that all compilers will always issue warnings based on the `@deprecated` Javadoc tag, though the Sun compilers currently do so. **Other compilers may not issue such warnings. Thus, using the @Deprecated annotation to generate warnings is more portable that relying on the @deprecated Javadoc tag.**

---

Resuming: if you want to deprecate a method implementation you must deprecate both, interface and implementation.

SOURCES [1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/deprecation/deprecation.html) [2](http://www.coderanch.com/t/369370/java/java/deprecated-interface-methods) [3](http://www.codejava.net/java-core/the-java-language/deprecated-annotation-examples)

Comment: Thanks for fast and adequate answer. Sadly there is no word about it at: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/predefined.html